# Saving from eloquent constructor in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, I'm currently working on a browser game in Laravel. So far I love the framework, but I haven't really got much experience, and I just can't get this to work.

Basically I'm trying to update all users whenever they are instantieted, as there is no reason update them when they are not used. But calling this function from the constructor doesn't update the user, it only works when I call the function outside the constructor.

Have I missed anything, or is it just not possible?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


public function __construct($arguments = array())
{
    parent::__construct($arguments);

    $this->updateHp();
}


public function updateHp()
{
    $this->hp_last = time();
    $this->save();
}   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent is a static class, data is fetched on query (find, first, get) and when you create a model you have just a blank model, with no data on it. This is, as example, the point where you have some data available:

```
public static function find($id, $columns = array('*'))
{
    if (is_array($id) && empty($id)) return new Collection;

    $instance = new static;

    return $instance->newQuery()->find($id, $columns);
}
```

Before one of those query methods, you have void.

So you probably cannot do that during __construct because your model is still blank (all nulls). This is what you can do to make it, somehow, automatic:

First, during boot, create some creating and updating listeners:

```
public static function boot()
{
    static::creating(function($user)
    {
        $user->updateHp($user);
    });

    static::updating(function($user)
    {
        $user->updateHp($user);
    });

    parent::boot();
}

public function updateHp()
{
    $this->hp_last = time();

    $this->save();
}
```

Then, every time you save() a model it will, before saving, fire your method:

```
$user = User::where('email', 'acr@antoniocarlosribeiro.com')->first();

$user->activation_code = Uuid::uuid4();

$user->save();
```

If you want to make it somehow automatic for all your users. You can hook it to a login event. Add this code to your global.php file:

```
Event::listen('user.logged.in', function($user) 
{
   $user->updateHp();
})
```

Then in your login method you'll have to:

```
if ($user = Auth::attempt($credentials))
{
    Event::fire('user.logged.in', array($user)); 
}
```

Comment: But isn't things fetched in the parent constructor, which is called first?

Comment: Eloquent is a static class, data is fetched on query (find, first, get) and when you create a model you have just a blank model, with no data on it.

Comment: What you could also do is to overload some methods, like find, and hook your update in those methods, but you may have to overload a lot of them...

Comment: Ah, of course.
But then if i wan't a function to be run on ALL pages in laravel, what is the best way to implement that.

Comment: Edited to provide a more Laravel(ish) way of making sure you'll get this ran to everyone, via events.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you shouldn't do that. If you use the code:

```
$user = new User();
```

you would like to be run:

```
$this->hp_last = time();
$this->save();
```

and what exactly should happen in this case? New user without id should be created with property `hp_last` ?

I think that's not the best idea.

You should leave it in the function then you can use:

```
$user = new User();
$user->find(1);
$user->updateHp();
```

That makes much more sense for me.

Comment: I am aware of that. And i would also, on the function, make a check whether the hp_last is over 1, to see if it is a new user or not.

But calling the function all the time is just annoying. Isn't it possible to do it from the constructor?